# Positive sectional curvature & finite isometry group

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Is there a known example of a compact Riemannian manifold with positive sectional curvature that doesn't have continuous symmetry (i.e. there are no nontrivial Killing fields)?

I'm more interested in the case when the manifold is even-dimensional (related to the Hopf conjecture on Euler characteristic) but I'd be interested in the general case as well.

Comment: Here's a computation of isometry groups of elliptic three-folds: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0010077.pdf

Comment: It seems that for the standard ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} =1$, it has discrete isometry when $a, b, c$ are distinct.

Comment: "Most" Riemannian manifolds have no nontrivial isometries at all. A way to get lots of examples with positive curvature is to start with a round sphere, and then small "dents" in it, centered at finitely many points in general position. (Or, more rigorously, modify the standard metric in a neighborhood of each of finitely many points by a small bump function in local coordinates.)

Comment: @JackLee Do you know of a way to make the genericity statement ("most") rigorous?

Comment: One interpretation of "most" is "open and dense in the $C^\infty$ topology." See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0182) by Pierre Mounod.